# Unable to install Dolphin emulator 4?

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, emulation

I am facing a problem when I want to to install Dolphin emulator 
This is the error that I have:

> dependency is not satisfiable
>   libavcodec56(>=6:11~beta1)|libavcodec-extra56(>=6:11.2)

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Please include the output of `apt-cache policy dolphin-emu-master` in your question. Are you using any PPAs for this package?

Comment: How may I do that?

Comment: 1) Click the [edit] link underneath your question, 2) open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T), 3) enter the command and press ENTER, 4) select its output with the mouse pointer and copy and paste it (by middle click or context menu (open with right click)) into the editor field from step 1), 5) format it as [code listing](/editing-help#code) with the `{}` button in the toolbar, 6) click *Save edits*.

Comment: I'm trying to install it from .deb package using GUI package installer !

Comment: Ok, good to know. Where did you get the package from? There might be some useful information about it at its source.

Comment: from  the offical website !

Comment: I can only find binaries for Windows and OS X on the [official download page](http://www.dolphin-emulator.com/download.html). Can you please provide a link to your source?

Comment: Hm, there's another [official looking site](https://dolphin-emu.org/), that [suggests installing from a PPA](https://wiki.dolphin-emu.org/index.php?title=Installing_Dolphin#Ubuntu). I suggest you try the stable release, not the development release.

Comment: Unfoutuentaly it is the only offilcal site and there is no PPA to insall it 
all what I need to know how can find the newer verisons of that libaray 
' libavcodec56'

Comment: You still haven't told me source. It'll be very hard to help you without taking a look at the description surrounding whatever package you're trying to install. The PPA exists [as described in my aforementioned link](https://wiki.dolphin-emu.org/index.php?title=Installing_Dolphin#Ubuntu). You can [inspect its packages on Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~dolphin-emu/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+packages?field.name_filter=&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=trusty).